# How to iterate in google ocr textannotation object with php?

Tags: php, ocr, google-vision

I'm trying to get pages, paragraphs, blocks, etc
similar to the code below but in PHP.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/fulltext-annotations

```
"""Returns document bounds given an image."""
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

bounds = []

with io.open(image_file, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)

response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
document = response.full_text_annotation

# Collect specified feature bounds by enumerating all document features
for page in document.pages:
    for block in page.blocks:
        for paragraph in block.paragraphs:
            for word in paragraph.words:
                for symbol in word.symbols:
                    if (feature == FeatureType.SYMBOL):
                        bounds.append(symbol.bounding_box)

                if (feature == FeatureType.WORD):
                    bounds.append(word.bounding_box)

            if (feature == FeatureType.PARA):
                bounds.append(paragraph.bounding_box)

        if (feature == FeatureType.BLOCK):
            bounds.append(block.bounding_box)

# The list `bounds` contains the coordinates of the bounding boxes.
```

I was able to create this

```
require AUTOLOAD; 
use Google\Cloud\Vision\VisionClient;
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\TextAnnotation;

$path = 'img scr';

$imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();

$image = file_get_contents($path);
$response = $imageAnnotator->documentTextDetection($image);
$texts = $response->getFullTextAnnotation();
```

But I'm facing a hard time trying to iterate with the TextAnnotation object.
Either I got the message `Cannot use object of type Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\TextAnnotation as array` .Even if I try to force the object as array.

Here is the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.135.0/vision/v1/textannotation) from google for the object

Answer (score 2):

To get the result from `$response->getFullTextAnnotation();` try the following:

```
$response->getFullTextAnnotation()->getText();
```